# How to retrieve data from 2 tabels in firebase db android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here is my db format:

```
{
  "classes": {
    "class1": {
      "name":"C1"
    },
    "class2": {
      "name":"C2"
    }
  },
  "students": {
    "student1": {
      "name":"S1"
    },
    "student2": {
      "name":"S2"
    }
  },
  "classes_enrollments": {
    "class1": {
      "student1": true,
      "student2": true
    },
    "class2": {
      "student1": true
    }
  },
  "students_enrollments": {
    "student1": {
      "class1": true,
      "class2": true
    },
    "student2": {
      "class1": true
    }
  }
}
```

I want to get data like : ***class1 named C1, has 2 students S1 and S2***

I tried this way

```
database.child("classes_enrolments").addValueEventListener(eventListener);
```

but the output is just the data of `classes_enrolments` node: `{class2={student1=true}, class1={student2=true, student1=true}}`

How to achieve it, please?

Thank you

Comment: A little bit later but have you solved the problem?

Comment: Unfortunately No, still searching for solution, @AlexMamo if you can help, I'd be grateful

Comment: Ok, I'll write you an answer right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this, please use the cpde below:

```
String class1 = "class1";
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference nameRef = rootRef.child("classes").child(class1).child("name");
ValueEventListener nameValueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot nameDataSnapshot) {
        String className = nameDataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
        Log.d(TAG, class1 + " named " + className);

        DatabaseReference class1Ref = rootRef.child("classes_enrollments").child(class1);
        ValueEventListener class1EventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                long numberOfStudent = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
                Log.d(TAG, "has " + numberOfStudent + " students");

                for(DataSnapshot studentDataSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String student = studentDataSnapshot.getKey();

                    DatabaseReference studentsRef = rootRef.child("students");
                    DatabaseReference studentRef = studentsRef.child(student);
                    ValueEventListener studentsValueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                String name = ds.child("name").getValue(String.class);
                                Log.d(TAG, name);
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                            Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
                        }
                    };
                    studentRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(studentsValueEventListener);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
            }
        };
        class1Ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(class1EventListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
nameRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(nameValueEventListener);
```

In order to solve this, you should first get the name of the class, the query to get the number of student and in the end to get the name of the students. The result in the logcat will be:

```
class1 named C1
has 2 students
S1
S2
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will try it when return to my machine :)

Comment: Ok, keep me posted.

Comment: yes it works, Thank you very much, but I get student's name from snapshot directly as  ``` String name = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class);
                                        Log.d(TAG, name); ``` Also i have question Is this approach is the best for performance?

Comment: if the student is belong to more groups like friends and sports, how to get all data about that student ?

Comment: Regarding *Is this approach is the best for performance?*, those queries are according to your database sturcuture you have and are fast. All the time we structure the database according to the queries we want to perform. Regarding *if the student is belong to more groups like friends and sports, how to get all data about that student ? *, it might be considered another question since it will have a new schema. So in this case, I recommend you post another fresh question using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so me and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: I shared new question, if you can help me, I'd be grateful :)
https://stackoverflow.com/q/58440133/5055780