# How to get full data from many to many relationship in firebase db android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, many-to-many

I have a class which is part of a school and this class has teachers and students, all of them has name and maybe has phone number , I want to get the full data for the classes 
but firstly, could you advice me, what is the best for performance and maintaining from the following Dbs  :

1st one

```
 "schools":{
   "school1":{
     "class1":{
       "name":"SC1",
       "teachers":[{
         "name":"T1"
       }, {
         "name":"T2"
       }],
       "students":[
         {"name":"S1"},
         {"name":"S2"}
         ]
     }
   }
.
.
.
.
.
.
.

 }
```

and the 2nd

```
  "school":{
    "school1":{
      "name":"SC1"
    },
    "school2":{
      "name":"SC2"
    }
  },
  "classes": {
    "class1": {
      "name": "C1"
    },
    "class2": {
      "name": "C2"
    }
  },
  "students": {
    "student1": {
      "name": "S1",
      "phone":"123456789"
    },
    "student2": {
      "name": "S2",
      "phone":"123456789"
    },
    "student3": {
      "name": "S3",
      "phone":"123456789"
    },
    "student4": {
      "name": "S4",
      "phone":"123456789"
    }
  },
  "teachers": {
    "student1": {
      "name": "T1",
      "phone":"123456789"
    },
    "student2": {
      "name": "T2",
      "phone":"123456789"
    },
    "student3": {
      "name": "T3",
      "phone":"123456789"
    },
    "student4": {
      "name": "T4",
      "phone":"123456789"
    }
  },
  "classes_enrollments": {
    "class1": {
      "teacher1": true,
      "teacher3": true,
      "student1": true,
      "student2": true
    },
    "class2": {
      "teacher2": true,
      "teacher4": true,
      "student3": true,
      "student4": true
    },
    "class3": {
      "teacher1": true,
      "teacher2": true,
      "student3": true,
      "student4": true,
      "student1": true,
      "student2": true
    }
  },
  "student_friends": {
    "student1": {
      "student2": true
    },
    "students2": {
      "student1": true,
      "student3": true
    },
    "students3": {
      "student2": true
    }
  },
  "teacher_friends": {
    "teacher1": {
      "teacher2": true
    },
    "teacher2": {
      "teacher1": true,
      "teacher3": true
    },
    "teacher3": {
      "teacher2": true
    }
  }
```

and for the 2nd way how to get the full data for the class1: in which school and it's name and count of teachers and students and their names and phones

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would mix those two.

For code simplicity and reading performance of individual class details, the 2nd scheme would indeed be messy. The 1st scheme would be better, but with some improvements.

Keep the `teachers` and `students` paths at root, just like in the 2nd scheme.

Add `teacher_enrollments` and `student_enrollments` path at root, to save the ids of the classes that each teacher/student is associated with.

Don't save class teachers and students as arrays inside classes, but use maps instead, similar to what you're saving in the root `teachers` and `students` path.

That way, when you edit a teacher from the root path, you can also get a list of all their associated classes (the ids) from the enrollments path, and do a multi-path update for these classes, to update the teacher/student details in each associated class.

If you have lots of data, you might want to maintain a separate path for class summaries, so that you can easily show a list of classes, without having to download the data for all included teachers and students (which would be present multiple times in all these classes).

When you delete a class, you would also want to do a multi-path update to delete all associated enrollments. <s>If the total number of students and teachers is not too big, you can just delete the enrollments for ALL teacheres/students. If you have lots of teachers/students, you could keep your `classes_enrollments` path (but with intermediate `teachers` and `students` before the ids), so that you can make an update with only the required teacher/student ids.</s> (it's actually a lot simpler. You already have the teacher/student IDs in the class info)

```
// How to delete a class in JavaScript.
// For Java, use updateChildren() instead of update(),
// and supply it with a HashMap instead of a plain object.
const classToDelete = { id: 'class1', teachers: ..., students: ..., school: ... };
const updateObject = {
  ['classes/'+classToDelete.id]: null },
  ['schools/'+classToDelete.school.id+'/classes/'+classToDelete.id]: null },
};
Object.keys(classToDelete.teachers).forEach(teacherId => {
  updateObject['teachers/'+teacherId +'/classes/'+classToDelete.id] = null;
});
Object.keys(classToDelete.students).forEach(studentId=> {
  updateObject['students/'+studentId+'/classes/'+classToDelete.id] = null;
});
dbRef.update(updateObject);
```

Example database structure (slightly different than instructed, but using the same concepts):

```
"schools": {
    "school1": {
        "id": "school1",
        "name": "The best school",
        "classes": {
            "class1": {
                "id": "class1",
                "name": "The best class"
            }
        }
    }
},
"classes": {
    "class1": {
        "id": "class1",
        "name": "The best class",
        "teachers": {
            "teacher1": {
                "id": "teacher1",
                "name": "The best teacher",
                "phone": "123"
            }
        },
        "students": {
            "student1": {
                "id": "student1",
                "name": "The best student",
                "phone": "456"
            }
        },
        "school": {
            "id": "school1",
            "name": "The best school"
        }
    }
},
"teachers": {
    "teacher1": {
        "id": "teacher1",
        "name": "The best teacher",
        "phone": "123",
        "classes": {
            "class1": {
                "name": "The best class",
                "school": {
                    "id": "school1",
                    "name": "The best school"
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
"students": {
    "student1": {
        "id": "student1",
        "name": "The best student",
        "phone": "456",
        "classes": {
            "class1": {
                "name": "The best class",
                "school": {
                    "id": "school1",
                    "name": "The best school"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: thank you for your answer, but could provide it with java code and db scheme ?

Comment: @Tarek I'm not very confident with Java without an IDE :) But I'm sure there are plenty of examples on multi-path updates. I added a sample db scheme, take a look.

Comment: Thank you for your update, but I think that this scheme is very easy to get all data for any 'node' but too much complicated and hard to update, if teacher1 is teacher for many classes I should copy the same data many times and if this data became old it should be updated in many paths.. is it ?

Comment: @Tarek Yes, for any change in a teacher/class, you must update the related classes/ teachers. But it's not hard to do, because each teacher/class "knows" which are the related teachers/classes. So you can make all your views with a single read. In an Android app that we stored separately the IDs of "students of a class" and had to do individual reads for each "student", performance was bad, when there were many (like 100+) "students". When we switched to duplicating the "students" data into the classes, it went lightning fast.

Comment: If you don't want to do this in your app directly, you can make Cloud Functions that would do the denormalization for your data. But, really, give it a try.

Comment: ok is there a tutorial explain how to achieve that "denormalization" with firebase?

Comment: This video explains denormalization https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vKqXSZLLnHA and this one explains how to maintain consistency using multi-path updates https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i1n9Kw3AORw . The rule of thumb is that you should structure your database according to your views.